# Tomcat webapp isn't working

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, resteasy

i've created a maven webapp with tomcat 7. This webapp also has a RESTful WebService, but i don't believe that's doing something wrong since it actually works.
Going to show you what i got for now:

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>angular-js</groupId>
    <artifactId>angular-js</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.resteasy</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.scannotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>scannotation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>AngularJS Application</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

This is my project structure:

http://puu.sh/5FJGZ.png
[image]

I believe it's all okay, but for some reason, when i go to `http://localhost:8080/angular-js` or `http://localhost:8080/angular-js/index.htm` i get a 404 error from tomcat that the resource isn't found.

Do you know what is wrong in here ? :S been working on this for hours!!!! getting desperate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your web.xml file is in wrong place. It should be on WEB-INF folder not lib

Comment: as @JorgeCampos said web.xml is missed. it should in WEB-INF folder and index.html should in webapp folder

Comment: @mikeyaworski: Please use `<!-- language: foo -->` in the body text instead of editing the tags to be less relevant in case the syntax highlight inferred from question tags is wrong. I rolled back your edit and added the inline syntax highlight hints now.

Comment: thanks for that, didn´t know about that feature in the code block :)

Comment: @laalto I didn't know you could do that, but you still shouldn't have changed the tags back. It still has nothing to do with Java, and is about XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change location web.xml file because in your project structure

web.xml is in lib folder within all jars but eclipse create this one in WEB-INF directly

Comment: it worked!!! thanks!!! :') i know the web.xml goes into the WEB-INF folder and not lib but i tried putting it there since in a tutorial video, after setting the webapp archetype, the eclipse automatically added the web.xml in the lib folder, weird. But anyway if you modify the <webXml> configuration in the pom.xml to the WEB-INF/lib it will look inside the lib and not WEB-INF :P but thanks, the problem was the misplacement of the index.htm.